# d3 with Highchart Jasper Export Issue using Custom Visualization Component(CVC)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm developing a Grouped Stacked Bar chart refer this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/), the chart is rendering on jasperserver but it is not exporting to PDF and Excel. I'm receving following Exception:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error while executing the javascript file to generate the SVG image: External process did not end properly; exit value: 500; process output: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'HighchartsAdapter.addEvent') c:%5CJaspersoft%5Cjasperreports-server-6.0.1%5Capache-tomcat%5Ctemp%5Ccv_component_1432214735797_1720781342.html:25 c:%5CJaspersoft%5Cjasperreports-server-6.0.1%5Capache-tomcat%5Ctemp%5Ccv_component_1432214735797_1720781342.html:25 c:%5CJaspersoft%5Cjasperreports-server-6.0.1%5Capache-tomcat%5Ctemp%5Ccv_component_1432214735797_1720781342.html:25 c:%5CJaspersoft%5Cjasperreports-server-6.0.1%5Capache-tomcat%5Ctemp%5Ccv_component_1432214735797_1720781342.html:25 c:%5CJaspersoft%5Cjasperreports-server-6.0.1%5Capache-tomcat%5Ctemp%5Ccv_component_1432214735797_1720781342.html:67 SCRIPT_ERROR Script did not produce any SVG within 3 seconds. Possible script error.

This is my Script written on Jasper Studio using (CVC) component

```
define('d3Circle',['d3', 'highcharts'], function (d3) {
 return function (instanceData) {   
 var w = instanceData.width,
     h = instanceData.height;
 var margin = 20;
 var diameter = Math.min(w,h) - margin;
    var svg = jQuery("#" + instanceData.id).highcharts({ 
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        stack: 'female'
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        stack: 'female'
    }]
});
};
```

});

Thank you

Comment: It looks you didn't include jQuery or Highcharts adapter.

Comment: I'm using it within jasper server, so it already have the jQuery and what is this Highcharts Adapter... i googled it but didn't got any standard info on this.

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is loaded before Highcharts. And [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation) you can read about Highcharts standalone framework (A - #2 paragraph).

Comment: @Pawel,  tried that but no use. I'm using it in jasper using "Custom Visualization Component". Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with Jasper soft. Anyway, that bug suggest missing jQuery or Adapter. Or wrong order of files (first jQuery/Adapter, then Highcharts).

Comment: I'll work on this @Pawel thanks a lot for your replies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've to have Phantom.js configured to all the exports supported by JasperServer.